# What is the Flow Run Size Limit of a notebook activity in Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure-synapse

I created a large spark notebook and ran it successfully in Azure Synapse.  Then I created a new pipeline with a new notebook activity pointing to the existing spark notebook.  I triggered it and it failed with the error message:

```
ErrorCode=FlowRunSizeLimitExceeded, ErrorMessage=Triggering the pipeline failed 
due to large run size. This could happen when a run has a large number of 
activities or large inputs used in some of the activities, including parameters.
```

There is only one activity in that pipeline; so, it can't be the number of activities being exceeded.  I googled flow run size limit on activity and there was no result.  What is the flow run size limit on the notebook activity?

Here is the information:

| Filename | Blob Size |
| --- | --- |
| [UID_ISO_FIPS_LookUp_Table.csv](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/UID_ISO_FIPS_LookUp_Table.csv) | 396 KiB |
| [05-11-2021.csv](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/05-11-2021.csv) | 630 KiB |
| https://ghoapi.azureedge.net/api | 476 KiB |

| Type | Size | Cell Total | Cluster Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .ipynb notebook | 668,522 bytes | 43 cells | Small (4 vCores / 32 GB) - 3 to 3 nodes |

Here is the error message after triggering the pipeline
[image: error message after triggering the pipeline]

Here is the sample code in the notebook.  The purpose is to join three files into a single file with a single table.  Some processing of csv files are filtering, selecting columns, renaming columns, and aggregating values.

[image]

[image: sample code]

Could someone explain why the error message occurred?

Comment: What type of processing are you doing on the csv?  Can you post some sample code, non-sensitive of course?  Have you considered copying the csv into a database table using the Copy activity then using the notebook?  What size Spark pool are you using?  Do larger ones help?

Comment: @wBob The size of the [public covid file](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/05-11-2021.csv) is 8.62kb.  The size of spark pool is  
`Small (4 vCores / 32 GB) - 3 to 3 nodes`  After having completed a workshop, I was trying to use Azure synapse alone.  Haven't considered coping a csv file into a database before using a notebook.  Will try it later.   Also I will post a sample code so that you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to import that .csv with the following Python code on a small Spark pool:

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://someContainer@somestorageAccount.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/csv/05-11-2021.csv', format='csv'
, header = True
)
display(df.limit(10))

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
```

Saving it as a temp view allows you to write some conventional SQL to query the dataframe, eg

```
%%sql
SELECT SUM(deaths) xsum
FROM tmp
```

Comment: Thank you for your neat code.  After reading your answer, I debugged and retyped the python code.  As the result, the problem disappeared, which mystified me.  At least I got the notebook activity working well.